# Find the solution to the initial condition $ u(x,0)=\sin x \ $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Consider the following conservation law:

$$ u_t-xt^2 u_x=0 , \ -\infty <x <\infty,  \ t> 0 \ $$

(a) Find its Characteristics lines.

(b) Find the solution to the initial condition $$ u(x,0)=\sin x \ $$

**Answer:**

(a)

$ u_t-xt^2u_x=0  $

The characteristic equation is

$ \frac{dt}{1}=\frac{dx}{-xt^2}=\frac{du}{0} \ $

Solving , we get

$$ u=constant=c , \\ \ln(x)-\ln(x_0) =-\frac{t^3}{3} \ $$

Now what to do ?

what would be characteristic line ?

Comment: Follow: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2776896/pde-ivp-characteristics-why-is-my-method-wrong/2776939#2776939

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint.

$$
u(x,t) = \Phi(xe^{\frac{t^3}{3}}) = \sin\left(xe^{\frac{t^3}{3}}\right)
$$

and for $t=0\rightarrow u(x,0) = \sin(x)$

Comment: what are the characteristic lines?

Comment: The characteristic lines come from $\frac{dt}{1}=\frac{dx}{x t^2}$ giving $C_0 = x e^{\frac{t^3}{3}}$

Answer (score 4):

we have the Lagrange equations
$$\frac {dt}{1}=\frac {dx}{-xt^2}$$
$$
\begin{cases}
dz=0 \implies z=C_2  \\
-t^2 {dt}=\frac {dx}{x} \implies \ln(x)+\frac {t^3}3=C_1
\end{cases}
$$
$$f(C_1)=C_2 \implies u(x,t)=f(\ln(x)+\frac {t^3}3)$$
$$ u(x,o)=\sin(x) \implies u(x,0)=f(\ln(x))=\sin(x) \implies f(x)=\sin(e^x)$$
Therefore
$$u(x,t)=f(\ln(x)+\frac {t^3}3)$$
$$u(x,t)=\sin(\exp(\ln(x)+\frac {t^3}3)) $$
$$\boxed{u(x,t)=\sin(xe^{\frac {t^3}3})} $$